# AWS Lambda did not able to send SNS

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have one lambda function that will insert users as well as send sns insert and validation of user is working well while inserting. Like while user insert I have to validate whether the user is exists or not.

```
    'use strict';
    var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
    var mysql = require("mysql");
    exports.handler = function (event, ignore, callback) {
        var rds;

        var input = {};
        var ret;
        // rds.query();
        if (event.type === undefined || event.username === undefined || event.username === null || event.type === null || event.username === "") {
            console.log(`Missing username or type`);
            ret = {
                "level": "error",
                "message": `Missing username or type`
            };
            callback(JSON.stringify(ret));
        }

        input.stage = event.stage;
        input.test = {};
        input.test.error = `User ${event.username} already exists;`;
        input.test.query = `select * FROM users WHERE user_id = "${event.username}";`;
        input.test.validate = function (rows) {
            if (null === rows || 0 === rows.length) {
                return true;
            }
            // rds.execute(input.test, callback)
            console.log(`User ${event.username} already exists;`);
            return false;
        };

        input.query = `INSERT INTO users(user_id, Type, Reason) VALUES ("${event.username}", "${event.type}", "${event.reason}");`;
        input.action = function (res) {
            console.log(`User ${event.username} added`);
            ret = {
                "level": "info",
                "message": `User ${event.username} added`
            };



            return JSON.stringify(ret);
        };

        //now insert the user by


    var conn = mysql.createConnection(config);

    conn.connect(function (err) {
        if (null !== err) {
            var message = {
                "level": "error",
                "message": err
            };
            console.log(message);
            callback(JSON.stringify(message));
        }
    });

    conn.query(input.query, callback);

      var sns = new AWS.SNS({accessKeyId: "aa", secretAccessKey: "aaa",region: 'us-east-1'});
      sns.publish({Message: "heelo user", TopicArn: "aa"}, function(err, data){
        if(err){console.log(err);}
         console.log(data);
});

    };
```

It is inserting data but not able to send SNS .  sns publish is not sending any message
Also it work for validate user but not able to send sns.

Got error

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2018-05-22T06:52:12.024Z 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f Task timed out after 30.03 seconds"
}

Request ID:
"95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f
REPORT RequestId: 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f  Duration: 30030.18 ms   Billed Duration: 30000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 36 MB  
2018-05-22T06:52:12.024Z 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
```

Comment: What error is being sent to the log? Also, why are you inserting access credentials into the `new AWS.SNS` line? You should simply assign a Role to the Lambda function and it will automatically receive credentials.

Comment: No error is comming but It is not sending sns

Comment: But while I am trying to send it by node console I can able to send

Comment: What permissions are associated with the access key you provided? You really should remove that access key from the code. There is rarely a need to include credentials in Lambda functions. Fix that first, then try to debug your SNS problem.

Comment: role of sns full access

Comment: got ``Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2018-05-22T06:52:12.024Z 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f Task timed out after 30.03 seconds"
}

Request ID:
"95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f
REPORT RequestId: 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f Duration: 30030.18 ms Billed Duration: 30000 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 36 MB 
2018-05-22T06:52:12.024Z 95066993-5d8c-11e8-9803-71c47d22473f Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
`` this error

Comment: The error message is: `Task timed out after 30.03 seconds` This means that your Lambda function did not finish because it hit the 30-second timeout. You either need to increase the timeout on the Lambda function (maximum = 5 minutes), or figure out why your code is taking so long to run. For example, add additional logging so you can see where it got to before being timed-out.

Comment: There are two problems, here, or possibly 3...  1. Your last query and the SNS request have a race condition; 2. You need to close the MySQL connection or set `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;`; and 3. Your function needs Internet access to contact SNS.

Answer (score 1):

I assume your Lambda function is configured within a VPC to enable access to your MySQL database. Could you please check whether your Lambda function is granted with internet access as explained in [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/)?

As SNS service is exposed as a public endpoint, it will require internet access to properly publish notifications to SNS.

To grant internet access, you will need to set up a NAT Gateway in a public subnet and associate it as the default route of the private subnets which are associated with the Lambda function.